# Bridging log4j for apache kafka to slf4j in akka

Tags: log4j, akka, slf4j, apache-kafka

not sure why I am not able to bridge log4j messages from apache kafka 0.8.1.1 to slf4j in akka application.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

The sbt dependencies:

```
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.8.1.1" exclude("javax.jms", "jms") exclude("com.sun.jdmk", "jmxtools") exclude("com.sun.jmx", "jmxri") withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.5",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
```

I have root logger in logback defined and akka application is logging fine but logs from apache kafka I am not able to make through? No duplicit binding etc.

Did I overlooked something?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding log4j from kafka dependencies solved my similar issue.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.8.2.0" exclude("log4j", "log4j") exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12")
```

Answer (score 0):

The sbt dependencies

```
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.8.2.0" exclude("log4j", "log4j") exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12"),
"org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.5"
```